# Printing a list of numpy arrays

Tags: python

I have a list of numpy-float arrays, but it prints as
`[[array([1 2 3 ...]), array([4 5 6 ...]), ...]`

How can I print it to look nicer, something like 
`[[1 2 3 ...], [4 5 6 ...], ...]`

Comment: That's a bad dupe @Austin — the OP is starting with a *python list* of numpy arrays.

Comment: @MarkMeyer, Does not matter. OP can iterate the *python list* and apply the same operation as in the dupe.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `tolist()`

```
import numpy as np

temp_list = []
for i in range(10):
    temp_list.append(np.zeros([5, 10]))
temp = np.array(temp_list)
temp.tolist()
```